# Embed html5 video player in facebook feed

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-graph-api, html5-video

Is it possible to embed html5 video player in facebook feed?

I tryed to setup OpenGraph meta tags, but after page sharing (http://autru.com/f) Facebook still doing post as link to website.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at present. You can specify flash with fallback to mp4 etc, but you cannot have a custom HTML5 player for mp4.